# Spring Webflux Websocket Client (ReactorNettyWebSocketClient) - not sending while messages are being received

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-webflux, spring-websocket, reactor-netty

I am trying to implement a WebSocket client for a [KuCoin crypto exchange resource](https://docs.kucoin.com/#general) in order to fetch current market data. The application is built on **Spring Boot**, and is using **Spring WebFlux ReactorNettyWebSocketClient** for exchange API communication.

The API documentation provides that after a handshake, the client has to send a request to [subscribe](https://docs.kucoin.com/#subscribe) to a certain channel ([5 best ask/bid orders](https://docs.kucoin.com/#level2-5-best-ask-bid-orders) in my case). Once the data starts streaming from the server, it is necessary to keep the stream opened by sending periodic ["Ping" messages](https://docs.kucoin.com/#ping). With that in mind, I came up with the following code (demo):

```
// sample token, valid can be obtained from: POST https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/bullet-public -> "data" -> "token"
String token = "2neAiuYvAU61ZDXANAGAsiL4-iAExhsBXZxftpOeh_55i3Ysy2q2LEsEWU64mdzUOPusi34M_wGoSf7iNyEWJ_FJZkT3sFi"
            + "L0St-iwQclmJ_Sarx5w80udiYB9J6i9GjsxUuhPw3BlrzazF6ghq4LwBeRfXaJvyCxEfL2zsVCuw=.wjcFO2RaGwCtkQxvSvCqDA==";
        URI wsUri = URI.create("wss://ws-api.kucoin.com/endpoint");
        URI fullUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(wsUri).queryParam("token", token).build().toUri();
        new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient().execute(fullUri, session ->
            session.send(
                Mono.just(session.textMessage("{\"id\":1,\"type\":\"subscribe\",\"topic\":\"/spotMarket/level2Depth5:BTC-USDT\"}")))
                   .thenMany(
                       Flux.merge(session.receive().doOnNext(wsMessage -> log.info("Received message: {}", wsMessage.getPayloadAsText())),
                                  Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).doOnNext(aLong -> {
                                      session.send(Mono.just(session.textMessage("{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"ping\"}")));
                                      log.info("Sent ping message");
                                  })))
                   .then()).subscribe();
```

Unfortunately, with this implementation, **Ping message is not sent**, and the connection is closed after a minute. However, from the logs I see that Flux side action for sending Ping is being invoked:

```
2021-10-24 12:16:31,372 INFO  pr.ddsd.ws_t_cpta.web.client.ws.WSExchangeClient: Received message: {"type":"message","topic":"/spotMarket/level2Depth5:BTC-USDT","subject":"level2"...
2021-10-24 12:16:31,464 INFO  pr.ddsd.ws_t_cpta.web.client.ws.WSExchangeClient: Sent ping message
2021-10-24 12:16:31,464 INFO  pr.ddsd.ws_t_cpta.web.client.ws.WSExchangeClient: Received message: {"type":"message","topic":"/spotMarket/level2Depth5:BTC-USDT","subject":"level2"...
```

So, why is the message not being sent while receiving data? Is it an incorrect implementation, or a Webflux ReactorNettyWebSocketClient's limitation? And what are the possible solutions for this issue? Any idea/advice/solution would be very helpful.

Many thanks!